# Is it possible to install a low profile shower pan this low and with almost no screws for the shower glass?

Tags: shower

I was in a store yesterday and I noticed this in display. Is it possible to get such a low profile setup for the pan? Does it need any type of membrane underneath and on the sides?

I am not seeing screws and support for the glass on the perimeter of the pan. How does this even stand up?

[image]

Comment: You're asking two different things. A shower pan can simply be an integrated depression in a tile floor, for example. There's no requirement that it have _any_ sides. If you're asking about the mounts for the glass, that's somewhat a proprietary thing. it does look like there are two screws or pins or something along the bottom edge.

Comment: sorry yes I kind of mixed the questions
what is the min height for a pan that sits on concrete? I want to buy the lowest possible

Comment: Zero-height thresholds are commonly installed for handicap accessibility (wheelchair access) situations. As I said, there's no minimum.

Comment: I need it to sit on concrete not set in it so there must be a minimum above which it does not make sense to build it. I get it that the drain will sit in a cavity in concrete but there must be a minimal height for the edge to retain the water within the glass cage

Comment: https://alistairmackintosh.co.uk/marble-stone-shower-trays/  this guys is saying as low as 30mm

Comment: I have built showers with only the slope to the drain. Glass block wall and tile not even a door you could only tell at the wall closer to the drain it depends how deep (the distance the water has to flow to the drain) how deep it needs to be.

Comment: I am new to tiles, showers and all ....I am handy though and I will watch a ton of videos before doing anything ...I am afraid that I can't take this risk to have a leak there and have a poor execution when building the shower pan myself. If there would be a fool proof method I would probably go for building one myself. There is tons of videos with big failures when building this yourself

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be fishing for some ideas for a project.

Well, here's the link to the [product in question](https://www.dullesglass.com/glass-shower-doors/sliding-glass-shower-doors/quadro-sliding-shower-doors), and it looks like the particular picture you posted is a display to sell the doors, so those raised edges on the pan might just be sprayed softwood for display purposes. As isherwood said, what you have at the base of your shower is a completely independent matter. It might help to put up some pictures of where you are planning to place your shower. Third floor in a Victorian home? Basement of new construction? Having a shower pan that stands the test of time is an intermediate to advanced-level project. I watched a contractor on YouTube yesterday who includes brazed copper sheets to build a custom, durable pan; as you can imagine, he's never had any complaints with leakage.

There are several options depending on your needs. Building an outdoor pool shower and an indoor shower have different needs. About the thinnest you can get would be [epoxy right over concrete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ann2e2SK0DQ). There are even binary marine epoxies that are durable enough to protect immersed wood (if you wanted something highly non-conventional). In this case, all you're worried about is sealing the concrete from moisture. There are [commercial drain systems](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Shower-System/Drains/Schluter%C2%AE-KERDI-DRAIN/p/KERDI_DRAIN) that essentially lay a waterproof membrane that is integrated with the drain itself with a slender profile to fit the tile thickness. Another option is to create a low-profile with a [concrete shower pan over a subfloor](https://www.hunker.com/12001114/how-to-make-a-concrete-shower-pan). There are other options, like using exotic materials that are used when constructing in-ground pools. Most contractors have a couple of efficient methods and stick to them.

Hopefully that will give you some ideas. Where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: I am looking for something that I can buy off the shelf

Comment: So you're looking for some sort of fiberglass pan with a tiny lip on it that you're going to slap down and anchor your doors to?

Comment: Here's a quick Google-Amazon search on low-profile pans. https://www.amazon.com/Fiberglass-Shower-Pans/s?k=Fiberglass+Shower+Pans

Comment: called the store, it is made by these guys https://www.fiora.us/ and it is like composite stone and it is freaking expensive 1400 just fr the base

Comment: You don't have any experience with concrete? Posts, steps, countertops? The stuff is cheap, maybe $3.50 for 80lbs of 4000 PSI. You can tile over it, acid stain it, epoxy the stuff. Are you busting up the concrete to put the drain in, new construction, or is there an existing drain in the concrete?

Comment: They got some nice looking products!

Comment: there is an existing drain for a bath tub that I removed. They did not even bother to pour cement in the opening just filled it up with sand and slapped the bath tub on top of it, left more dirt under the tub instead of taking it out of the house.
I am a DIY so no previous experience with concrete. 
I just removed the tiles and there are some concrete adhesive that is still there attached I guess I will have to pour self leveling concrete before anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111630/discussion-between-j-d-and-minime).

Answer (score 0):

I just alled the store, it is made by these guys https://www.fiora.us/ and it is like composite stone and it is freaking expensive 1400CAD just for the base
So it is entirely possible to have a shower pan like that

Comment: https://www.lowes.ca/product/shower-bases/dreamline-slimline-shower-base-30-in-x-60-in-acrylic-black-330657169  this is much cheaper and black as I need it